# ¿Cómo obtener el ultimo registro insertado?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT *, t1.cec as a from centrosacceso as t1 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT top 1 max(a.fecha_acceso)  as fecha, B.cec
              FROM accesos A INNER JOIN emp B ON A.usuario = B.emp 
               INNER JOIN cec C ON B.cec = C.cec
               INNER JOIN centrosacceso D ON C.cec = D.cec 
               WHERE D.activo = 1 AND D.estado <> 'ESTADO DE MÉXICO' AND D.estado <> 'CIUDAD DE MÉXICO' 
                     AND A.fecha_acceso >= CONVERT(varchar , DATEADD(minute, -20,'6/3/2022 2:44:14')) 
                     AND A.aplicacion is null
                group by  B.cec) as t2 on t2.cec = t1.cec 
WHERE t1.activo = 1 and t1.estado <> 'ESTADO DE MÉXICO' and t1.estado <> 'CIUDAD DE MÉXICO'
```

Lo que esta haciendo esta consulta es sacarme la fecha superior de cada registro, para esto en la tabla de accesos se encuentra el campo fecha_accesos,pero ahora si agrego otro campo para ver información, ejemplo:

```
select *, t1.cec as a from centrosacceso as t1 
    left join (SELECT top 1 max(a.fecha_acceso)  as fecha, B.cec, B.nombre
              FROM accesos A INNER JOIN emp B ON A.usuario = B.emp 
               INNER JOIN cec C ON B.cec = C.cec
               INNER JOIN centrosacceso D ON C.cec = D.cec 
               WHERE D.activo = 1 AND D.estado <> 'ESTADO DE MÉXICO' AND D.estado <> 'CIUDAD DE MÉXICO' 
                     AND A.fecha_acceso >= CONVERT(varchar , DATEADD(minute, -20,'6/3/2022 2:44:14')) 
                     AND A.aplicacion is null
                group by  B.nombre,B.cec) as t2 on t2.cec = t1.cec 
                        where t1.activo = 1 and t1.estado <> 'ESTADO DE MÉXICO' and t1.estado <> 'CIUDAD DE MÉXICO'
```

Me muestra el primer registro no el ultimo. Agregue B.nombre.
Alguna idea de como resolver esto, espero se de a entender.

Comment: Sin conocer que representa cada tabla y como se relacionan es muy difícil responderte.  ¿Que es lo que esperas de la subconsuta? ¿Por que el TOP 1? Por lo pronto, yo no agregaría el nombre en la subconsulta sino en la consulta principal. Trata de explicar un poco más que es cada tabla y que es lo que estas buscanodo.

Answer (score 1):

La sentencia MySQL SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() te devuelve el número de la columna AUTOINCREMENT del último registro añadido.
En php puedes usar mysqli_insert_id() que hace exactamente eso.